# Shortening sentences with participles -> "After the girls had finished their dance, they left the dance floor"

Tags: past-participles

i have this sentence, i have to shorten using participles:

> After the girls had finished their dance, they left the dance floor.

In the solutions there's as this answer written:

> After **having** finished their dance the girls left the dance floor.

Why was this version chosen? Why wasn't

> After the girls had finished **dancing**, they left the dance floor

chosen? Is my version wrong or also possible? Is there a grammatical difference?

Comment: I would personally choose the one with "having" and the last option because that's how I would say it.

Comment: I’m not impressed with the examples in your book. You might say that the perfect is redundant because the past/anterior meaning is conveyed by "after". I actually find the examples slightly odd. The content seems to imply immediate succession, but the examples don’t carry that interpretation. I think it would be much better to say “After finishing their dancing (or dance), the girls left the dance floor”.

Comment: One way of "shortening" a sentence with participles is to not write words such as *after*. Thus, if I were going to complete this exercise, I might write either *Having finished their dance, the girls left the dance floor* or perhaps *Finishing their dance, the girls left the dance floor*. See [Finishing or having finished](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85029/finishing-or-having-finished).

Comment: To shorten with a participle would make it: **After finishing their dance, the girls left then dance floor**. That is the shortest way to write it using only a participle. Or as Alan has said: **Finishing their dance** etc.  After having finished their dance is not wrong, it's just heavier.

Comment: @Lambie Your first suggestion repeats mine. The perfect is redundant if "after" is used.

Comment: @toogley It is very important for you to understand that your version in **not wrong.** It is perfectly acceptable and grammatical. If our book states that the only "correct" answer is _After having finished their dance..._, then it is the book itself that is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The word after used as a conjunction means following the time that/later than the time that; when an action/event has finished/happened..  In light of this definition, the usage of finished, though not wrong, may be dropped as it sounds a bit superfluous. The following sentences convey almost the same meaning..

After dancing, the girls left the dance floor.

After having danced, the girls left the dance floor.

After having finished their dance, the girls left the dance floor.

After finishing their dance, the girls left the dance floor.

Of these sentences, the first sentence sounds more common and brief.

Moreover, these sentences indicate that it's the girls who danced and left.

As for the sentence "After the girls had finished  dancing,  they left the dance floor", it sounds a bit ambiguous.  The pronoun they may mean other people such as the boys who were singing on the dance floor.

Comment: But the versions that use both after and *having*  (*After having danced, After having finished their dance*) seem not quite right to such native speakers as BillJ  and myself because *after* is unnecessary here, and thus we would not use it.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=After+finishing%2Cafter+having+finished%2Cafter+he+had+finished%2Cafter+he+finished&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CAfter%20finishing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cafter%20having%20finished%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cafter%20he%20had%20finished%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cafter%20he%20finished%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Well, some people use it, per actually looking at the uses in Google books; I guess BillJ and I wouldn't. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the point of the exercise is to replace the subordinate clause with a participial phrase.   If that is the case, on the one hand, your answer does not do that.   On the other hand, the book's answer doesn't necessarily do that, either.

Your answer replaces the noun phrase "their dance" with the gerund "dancing".   You left the rest of the subordinate clause intact.   Your answer has a complete subordinate clause with the same structure as the original: a subject, a finite verb, and a direct object.

Your answer is grammatically correct.   Much like nouns, gerunds are good objects.   However, your answer misses the point of the exercise.   You did not replace the subordinate clause with something shorter.

The book's answer does not have a subordinate clause.   There is no subject in "after having finished their dance".

I label this use of "having finished" as a gerund.   I consider "having finished their dance" to be the object of the preposition "after".

Traditional English grammar makes a distinction between -ing forms that are used as gerunds and -ing forms that are used as participles.   Some modern grammars don't bother making that distinction.   It is possible that your book doesn't make this distinction.   It is also possible that your book usually makes this distinction but happens to make a mistake here.   On the basis of this one question alone, we have no way of knowing.

In either case, the answer that makes sense to me is one that removes both the subject and the preposition:

> Having finished their dance, the girls left the dance floor.

In this answer, "having finished their dance" is definitely a participial phrase.   It does not act as the object of anything.   It has no subject of its own.   It modifies the following independent clause and relates to the subject of that clause.

Here's the point:  when the subjects of the subordinate clause and the independent clause mean the same thing, you should be able to replace the subordinate clause with a phrase that doesn't have a subject.   Your answer is good English, but it is good English that still has two subjects.